# define Subdomain and url both points to one controller in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, url, backend

I am working on a laravel application in which it has simple urls like-  domain.com/shop  but i want to make two dynamic url for this like:

- domain.com/shop
- shop.domain.com

Both points to the same url dynamically.
I want to define sub domain url and and simple url for each user dynamically which points to the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after Much research and trying different ways I could solve the problem.

after using Acrylic DNS Proxy, I must use two different roots for the main and subdomains.

This is for Main Domain :

```
    // Match my own domain
Route::group(['domain' => 'tc.dev'], function()
    {
    Route::any('/', function()
    {
        return 'My own domain';
    }); 
});
```

**And another for handling subdomains:**

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{subdomain}.tc.dev'], function()
{
    Route::any('/', function($subdomain)
    {
        return 'Subdomain ' . $subdomain;
    });
});
```

In fact, The main thing was that I must use another Route to control routes that act On the main Domain While I was ignored.

Comment: But how do i handle links in the ui files as i want to redirect users according to the url they are using (ie:- subdomain or simple url).

Comment: make a helper file and make functions where you provide different functions to get redirects according to their subdomain